# Comparing HTML strings in Python

Tags: python, html, python-2.7

I have several parsers that grab HTML from news websites. To make sure website's structure hasn't changed, I run a simple test twice a day: compare manually confirmed HTML returned from `get_content()` that is stored in a text file to a result just returned from `get_content()`.

This comparison produces different results for different URLs. For example, the strings are identical for this URL: http://ria.ru/world/20160309/1387413601.html, but are different for this one: http://www.ntv.ru/novosti/1608256/. What am I missing here?

```
class TextParser(object):
    def __init__(self, site, tag, prop):
        self.site = site
        self.tag = tag
        self.prop = prop

    def __call__(self, url):
        soup = bs(get_resource(url), 'html.parser')
        article = soup.find(self.tag, self.prop)
        if article:
            self.clean(article)
            return article.encode_contents().strip()

    def clean(self, article):
        # Drop image, script, div inside content
        [s.extract() for s in article(['script', 'div', 'img', 'table',
                                   'aside'])]
        # Drop comments
        [element.extract() for element in
         article(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))]


parsers = [
    TextParser('ria.ru', 'div', {'id': 'article_full_text'}),
    TextParser('ntv.ru', 'div', 'smcntr')
]


def get_resource(url):
    request = urllib2.Request(url)
    try:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
        html = response.read()
    except (urllib2.HTTPError, urllib2.URLError) as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return
    finally:
        response.close()
    return html


def get_content(url):
    site = urlparse(url).netloc.replace('www.', '')
    parser = next((x for x in parsers if x.site == site), None)
    if parser:
        content = parser(url)
        if content:
            return content
        else:
            logging.warning('Parsing error. URL:' + url)
            return None
    else:
        logging.warning('Missing parser. URL:' + url)
        return None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    content_web = get_content('http://www.ntv.ru/novosti/1608256/')
    with open('texts/ntv.ru.txt', 'r') as f:
        content_file = f.read()

    print hashlib.md5(content_web).hexdigest()
    print hashlib.md5(content_file).hexdigest()
```

Comment: Why don't you manually compare the two strings/contents to find the difference? That would probably be a big clue (I don't mean manually read the HTML, I just mean a short script to iterate through two strings and find the first discrepancy)

Comment: @HumphreyTriscuit this might work. Still, I'd like to understand why my approach doesn't work.

Comment: @HumphreyTriscuit they look identical here too: https://www.diffchecker.com/diff

Comment: Your program has undefined names, which makes it hard for us to reproduce your results. Can you copy-paste a complete program that demonstrates the problem? See [mcve] for more info.

Comment: @Robᵩ sorry about that. Here'a working program with: https://yadi.sk/d/W8LoM_urq6ZpW. Just change the URL in get_content() and filename in open() to see that it works fine for http://ria.ru/world/20160309/1387413601.html.